# Left Join giving wrong result

Tags: sql

I am having 3 tables Products,  Order, Order_Placed

```
Products---------- Order---------------- Order_Placed
________________________________________________________
prod_id | -------| order_id | -------| prod_id  |order_id| 

1000----------------2001-------------------1000|2001


1001----------------2002-------------------1000|2002

1002--------------- 2003------------------1001|2001
```

So my query is something like this:

```
select P.Prod_ID, COUNT(*) 
from PRODUCTS P
LEFT JOIN ORDER_PLACED OP
ON P.PROD_ID= OP.PROD_ID
group by ....
```

so result should be:

```
Prod_Id  Count(*)

1001      2

1002      1

1003      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  `count(*)` can never return `0`.  Either it returns nothing (no row at all) or at least 1.

You want:

```
select P.Prod_ID, COUNT(OP.PROD_ID) 
from PRODUCTS
LEFT JOIN ORDER_PLACED OP
ON P.PROD_ID= OP.PROD_ID
group by ....
```

NOTE:

There was an attempt to add a qualifier to my response.  But `count(*)` cannot return `0` in any situation with a `group by`.  A zero would mean that there are no rows in the group.  And that in turn would mean that there are no rows in the output.  When there are no rows selected at all for a global aggregation, then it can return `0`.

Comment: He told you the way. Instead of COUNT(*), which counts rows, use COUNT(op.prod_id), which count non null op.prod_id values. This works because in the LEFT JOIN op.prod_id will be NULL when there is no matching order_placed row.